# How to start a Plex stream using python-PlexAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, scripting

I'm making a python script using the module `PlexAPI`. My goal is to start a stream on the client `Chrome`. The movie to view has the `key` `/library/metadata/1`.

Documentation and sources of code:

- [playMedia documentation](https://python-plexapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/client.html#plexapi.client.PlexClient.playMedia)
- [Example 4 is used but changed to fit my requirements](https://python-plexapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#usage-examples)
- [I'm using the `key` parameter](https://github.com/plexinc/plex-media-player/wiki/Remote-control-API#modified-commands)

```py
from plexapi.server import PlexServer
baseurl = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx'
token = 'xxxxx'
plex = PlexServer(baseurl, token)

client = plex.client("Chrome")
client.playMedia(key="/library/metadata/1")
```

This gives the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start_stream.py", line 7, in <module>
    client.playMedia(key="/library/metadata/1")
TypeError: playMedia() missing 1 required positional argument: 'media'
```

So I edit the file:

```py
client.playMedia(key="/library/metadata/1")
#changed to
client.playMedia(key="/library/metadata/1", media="movie")
```

But then I get a different error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start_stream.py", line 7, in <module>
    client.playMedia(key="/library/metadata/1", media="movie")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/plexapi/client.py", line 497, in playMedia
    server_url = media._server._baseurl.split(':')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_server'
```

I don't really understand what's going on. Can someone help?

Comment: Looking at the docs playmedia is expecting a library selection like `cars = plex.library.section('Movies').get('Cars')` then `client.playMedia(cars)`

Comment: you can look at the documentation here https://python-plexapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/client.html#plexapi.client.PlexClient.playMedia it

Comment: Long story short you need to create a media object then pass that to play media to do its thing

Comment: The problem is that you might have movies with the same name (parasite 1982 and parasite 2019). So if you then want to watch one of those, i wouldn't know what would happen. Which movie will it play when I do `plex.library.section('Movies').get('Parasite')`? That is why I want to use the key (which is unique for every movie) instead of what you said (and what is used in example 4).

Comment: but cant you use `media = plex.library.section("movies").search(title="parasites", year=1982)` the search method of section is very powerful. I dont have plex and never used the library but reading teh docs and the source code it seems it can support lots. I am not sure the exact format but you can defo search by many factors to filter or narrow done to a single movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work the following way:

```py
from plexapi.server import PlexServer
baseurl = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx'
token = 'xxxxx'
plex = PlexServer(baseurl, token)

key = '/library/metadata/1'

client = plex.client("Chrome")
media = plex.fetchItem(key)
client.playMedia(media)
```